# Why is order times generator power always a multiple of the group's order?

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory, finite-groups

$\DeclareMathOperator{\ord}{ord}$
Let $g$ be a generator of $Z^*_p$, where $p$ is a prime number.  Let $a = g^s$ be a non-quadratic residue in $Z^*_p$, that is, $J(a,p) = -1$, where $J$ describes the Jacobi symbol.  It seems that $$\ord(a,p) \times s = 0 \bmod{p - 1}.$$

Why is this true?

---

Here's a proof of the fact.

---

**Proof**. By the definition of order, we have

$$1 = a^{\ord(a,p)} = (g^s)^{\ord(a,p)} = g^{s \ord(a,p)}.$$

By the definition of generator, $\ord(g,p) = p - 1$, so $1 = g^{s \ord(a,p)}$ either implies $s \ord(a,p) = p - 1$, which is a multiple of $p - 1$, or $s \ord(a,p)$ is a multiple of $p - 1$.  Either way,

$$s \ord(a,p) = \ord(a,p) s = k (p - 1) = 0 \bmod{p - 1},$$

as desired.

---

Thanks @RoddyMacPhee for not leaving me alone on this.

Comment: $p-1$ is always divisible by the order of an element.  So really the question boils down to why is $s$ a multiple of their ratio .